# How to create 4 X 2 table in html

Tags: html, html-table

I want to create a table with 4 columns above and 2 columns below, like 
[image]

Please let me know how to possible in html table.
Thank You

Comment: dont you know about columnspan.?

Comment: yes, tried but not getting correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbps;</td>
        <td>&nbps;</td>
        <td>&nbps;</td>
        <td>&nbps;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbps;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbps;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: but the above columns width is not unique, so the second row's the second column start from first rows 3rd column

Comment: @Delphian i can not understand what you are saying please modified your question.

Comment: @Delphian as you can see you have div inside td and div has static width of 462px..either change it to 100% or auto...or just remove it because div is block level element that will take entire with automatically

Comment: Thank you Dipesh for the quick response & clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><td>
  <td><td>
  <td><td>
  <td><td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"><td>
  <td colspan="2"><td>
</tr>
</table>
```